# NSIS: How to disable keyboard and mouse keys without restarting the computer?

Tags: windows, exe, nsis

I want to disable / block the mouse click and keyboard typing for 6 seconds after launching a .exe file while displaying a advsplash.

Currently I manage to run a .exe file, activate the splash, block the keyboard and run a second .exe, but then, I need to restart the computer to unlock the mouse/keyboard.

Any idea on how to disable it without restarting the machine ?

Comment: How do block it so a restart is required?

Comment: Do you want to block input in just the program you started or all programs on the computer?!

Comment: I did not ask how long, I asked if you wanted to block input to just one application or all applications including the taskbar etc.   ...and why do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: I run the first exe., and I recovered a text input with keybd_event for transfer to the 2nd. exe if I click the tab or I touch I lose my data that's why I want to disable for a moment and reactive when my text input will be sent in the text input of the second application.exe

Comment: @Anders When I run the first exe., I retrieve a text input with keybd_event in order to transfer it to the 2nd .exe. During this process, if I click somewhere with the mouse or touch the tab key, the string won't be passed to the expected (and selected) field and my app won't work. This is why I want to disable it both mouse and keyboard for a while and then reactivate it when my string effectively reached the text input in the second .exe

Comment: @TahLam: How do you proceed to disable globally user input?

Comment: If you tell us what you're doing at the moment, we may be able to explain how to undo it at the end of the six seconds.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @HarryJohnston i want send from first.exe to second.exe a hidden serial that will be entered to inputtext directly (i'll use keybdevent) so in that time (6seconds) the user cant use the keyboard and mouse, or i must use a NewAdvsplach to hide that in background!!!!
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Yes, but *how are you blocking the keyboard*?  That's what we need to know.

Comment: I want block it, even the mouse if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you should never do.

If you want to do UI automation Windows already has [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Active_Accessibility) for that, using SendInput or keybd_event is not a good idea. Some apps steal foreground focus, this is just a fact and if that happens at the wrong time you end up sending input to the wrong window.